# Finding nearest point in SpatiaLite without GEOS

Tags: nearest-neighbor, sqlite

I want to find the nearest point having latitude and longitude stored as Point in SpatiaLite. I read this and it has this example:

```
SELECT feature_name, feature_class, 
     ST_Distance(Geometry, MakePoint(-70.250, 43.802)) AS Distance FROM XYGNIS 
WHERE distance &lt; 0.1 AND ROWID IN 
(SELECT ROWID FROM SpatialIndex 
  WHERE f_table_name = 'XYGNIS' AND search_frame = 
  BuildCircleMbr(-70.250,    43.802, 0.1)) 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 10
```

I cannot use it, however, since ST_Distance requiring compiling SpatiaLite with GEOS, which is in LGPL, which I cannot use. Is there a way I can do arithmetics to calculate distance and set that to a "variable" and then find the one with the minimal distance?

Comment: any reasons why you cannot use LGPL license? It is more of a commercial friendly license than GPL..

Comment: It's intended to be on the App store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with a smallish dataset and over a small area or not too concerned about accuracy (i.e. [distance over oblate spheroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae)), then you could just use the following:

```
SELECT
    feature_name,
    feature_class,
    ((X(Geometry)-X(loc))*(X(Geometry)-X(loc))) + ((Y(Geometry)-Y(loc))*(Y(Geometry)-Y(loc))) as distance
FROM
    XYGNIS,
    (SELECT MakePoint(-70.250, 43.802) as loc)
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10;
```

The added advantage here is that you're eliminating the need to square root each result by just ordering the square of the distance (i.e. dx^2 + dy^2).  You can square root a set of the results, if you need to display the actual distance, in a sub query.